# Google Drive SDK - Sorting results when querying large number of documents

Tags: java, sorting, google-drive-api

Until a few weeks age, when using Drive SDK full text querying, results were returned sorted by "last modified" by default, but now, results are returned sorted by relevance, and this has a large effect on an app that queries a very large number of files (so client side sorting is not an option).

I don't seam to find any documentation regarding to sort parameters, so could anyone help my on this? Are there sorting options not stated in the docs? Is there a workaround for this? (until Drive SDK, I used Document List API with documented sorting options)

Also, I've noticed that developers are requesting this since mid 2012 so what can we do? Please Google, tell us if we should give up using Drive SDK and switch to another platform/api.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct the older version of [Google Documents List API v2](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/v2/reference) allowed for `order by` as one of the default query [parameters](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/v2/reference#Parameters).

The current [Drive REST API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/) (which is the same as Google drive sdk) [files.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list) does not have this option [standard query parameters](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/query-parameters).

You will need to sort it in your code after you get the results back from the API

Comment: Well... it seams there is no other option :)

Comment: Btw, when you say Google drive api v2  you mean Document List API v2? and when you say Google drive api v3 you mean just Google Drive API?

Comment: reworded things to make it more clear.   I have also searched though the issue request log for drive.  No one has requested this I don't think.  You are welcome to add a feature request.  https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/list

Comment: The docs list API got as far as v3. The Drive API is a completely new API. Internally this is at v2, but the versions no longer carry the same significance as before. Previously a version was stable and new features were introduced in a new version. Now, new features and even breaking changes are applied within a version (as you're discovering :-) ).

Comment: The Drive API documentation is silent on the order of search results, which means Google can and will change it at its whim. For most users, the idea of downloading every file in order to then sort them locally is not a viable option. I suggest you look at something more creative such as monitoring the changes feed, including date in your search criteria, using private properties, etc etc.

Comment: The drive api is lame in this respect. The answer says to sort locally which is impractical except for trivial cases as it would require to page through the entire result set. Its lame because google does have it indexed since the drive.google.com page does allow to sort by name but they just havent exposed it on the api.

Comment: would the -1 person please explain why, so that I can improve my answers in the future.

Comment: Voted up because of the person who gave -1 randomly. I hate that.